# Flutter: How to Make an array with the JSON data

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to make an array with JSON, But I duplicate the same post.
I am using the REST API JSON plugin for WordPress

More information about **WP REST API**: https://v2.wp-api.org

This is my **JSON** code

```
    [
  {
    "id": 65,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 1 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 1</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 1...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 650,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 2 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 2</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 2...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 230,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 3 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 3</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 3...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
]
```

**My code**:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:peluqueriafran/WebView.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('http://**********:88/WordPress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/');
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

  return new Post.fromJson(responseJson);
}

class Post {
    final int id;
    final String title;
    final String body;
    final String urlimagen;
    final String linkWeb;

    Post({this.id, this.title, this.body, this.urlimagen, this.linkWeb});

   factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return new Post(
         title: json['title']['rendered'].toString(),
      );
   }
}
```

**WEB:** 

[image]

**App: - The last generated is selected, I would like to get all the post.**

I hope someone can help me out, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could change `fetchPost` to return a List of Posts, like:

```
Future<List<Post>> fetchPosts() async {
  http.Response response =
      await http.get('http://**********:88/WordPress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/');
  List responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  return responseJson.map((m) => new Post.fromJson(m)).toList();
}
```

and you could then utilize the `Future<List<Post>>` like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
    future: fetchPosts(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
      List<Post> posts = snapshot.data;
      return new ListView(
        children: posts.map((post) => Text(post.title)).toList(),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

`ListView` takes a List of children, just like `Column` etc. So you could use any of the Widgets that enclose a list of children

Comment: In case you need it, I give you my class

https://pastebin.com/b3AJeD3U

Comment: Añadí y él dice: El 'título' Getter no está definido para la clase 'Lista <Publicación>' Mira la imagen: https://imgur.com/a/fPdLtDm

Comment: You now have a List of Posts, so you have to turn it into a list of Widgets. `snapshot.data` is now a List so look into `ListView.builder`

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand, I have to use ListView.Builder to get the data?

Comment: added to the answer

Comment: @ Richard Heap and how it would be to get them in a ListView.builder?, And not in a ListView

Comment: @Santiago `itemBuilder` needs to be a method taking a context and an int that returns just one widget (based on the value of the int), for example: `itemBuilder: (_, i) => Text(posts[i].title)`

Answer (score 3):

```
{
  "key": "message",
  "texts": [
    {
      "lan": "en",
      "text": "You have pushed this button many times"
    },
    {
      "lan": "tr",
      "text": "Bu butona bir çok kez bastınız"
    },
    {
      "lan": "ru",
      "text": "Вы много раз нажимали кнопку"
    }
  ]
}

class Lang {
  final String key;
  final List<dynamic> texts;

  Lang(this.key, this.texts);

  Lang.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : key = json['key'],
        texts = json['texts'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'key': key,
        'texts': texts,
      };
}

class Texts {
  final String lan;
  final String text;

  Texts(this.lan, this.text);

  Texts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : lan = json['lan'],
        text = json['text'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'lan': lan,
        'text': text,
      };
}


  Map<String, dynamic> languages = json.decode(jsonCrossword);
  var user = new Lang.fromJson(languages);
```