# Flutter - split SQL Query result

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, flutter

This is a very basic question which I'm sure theres an easy answer to.
I have a database and a PHP server which currently pulls all data from the table (for testing purposes).

The result looks like this

```
[{"post_id":"1","createdon":"2018-11-10","content":"This is my first post"},{"post_id":"2","createdon":"2018-11-10","content":"This is my second post"}]
```

How would I in Flutter take the content of post_id[1], and load it into my array[0], and same with post_id[2] into my array[1]?

Comment: so is it basically breaking apart the json string. sorry completely new to development, and just getting my head round everything

Comment: yup found a good link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706500/flutter-how-to-make-an-array-with-the-json-data/50707138. I just needed to import dart.convert

Comment: Solution found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706500/flutter-how-to-make-an-array-with-the-json-data/50707138

Comment: yes i am aware of flutter.io. but I found my answer. I will take a look at the documentation also

Comment: https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json